# Get rows by id or all rows if id is 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that gets all rows in a table with a specific ID. What I want to do is get all rows from this table if the store_id is 0.

This is the code I use right now:

```
SELECT store_id, SUM(traffic) FROM traffic 
WHERE store_id = @store_id AND year = @year 
GROUP BY store_id
```

I want to change this query so that it returns all rows regardless of the store_id when @store_id = 0

Comment: And so what's your question ?

Comment: How can I change the query to return all rows, regardless of the store_id when @store_id is 0

Comment: you can try `WHERE store_id = @store_id or @store_id = 0 ) AND year = @year`

Comment: I assume you want to select all records if the given parameter is 0 (or/and `NULL`?!):

You should use an `If...Else` in your SP then. That's more efficient than using an `OR @store_id = 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below

```
SELECT store_id, SUM(traffic) FROM traffic 
WHERE (store_id = @store_id OR @store_id = 0) AND year = @year 
GROUP BY store_id
```

Comment: u r only 20 second faster then nicky +1 for tht

Comment: Wouldn't this query return all rows `where store_id = 0` even when a value other than zero is passed to the `@store_id` variable?

Comment: No, because it says `@store_id`, not `store_id`

Answer (score 1):

```
IF @store_id = 0
BEGIN
SELECT store_id, SUM(traffic) FROM traffic 
WHERE year = @year 
GROUP BY store_id
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT store_id, SUM(traffic) FROM traffic 
WHERE store_id = @store_id AND year = @year 
GROUP BY store_id
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Test your `store_id` before making a request. If the `store_id == 0`, then make another request to get all regarding the `store_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if @store_id may also be `NULL` then do the following

```
SELECT store_id, SUM(traffic) FROM traffic 
WHERE (store_id = @store_id OR ISNULL(@store_id, 0) = 0)
 AND year = @year 
GROUP BY store_id
```